# Creating an app which has extra functionality in v11 but still runs in v7

Tags: android, compatibility, android-3.0-honeycomb

I've had a problem with this and have been running my head up against it and couldn't see how to use an ActionBar in the app when running on v11/3.0+ and then use an in house ActionBar in v7/2.1

The problem is that when you use any of the tags (such as `android:actionBarStyle`) or libraries from v11 library, your app will no longer compile with a library lower than v11. Therefore you won't be able to run it on a phone.

***However***

I've been looking at the source to the Google IO 2011 application and it uses v7 as a default library. It is designed however to use the ActionBar as it has the above tag in it (`android:actionBarStyle`). But since I have a built version on my phone and it has alot of code for creating a fake ActionBar when on devices lower than v11 it obviously should be able to be built on both.

Obviously there is a peice of the puzzle I'm missing. How do I get the Google IO 2011 app building? What mechanism is in place which allows you to develop for multiple versions at once?

Someone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid Question which comes from confusing myself over 3 different issues I'm juggling.

Apps built with v11 library will happily run on a phone as long as the `android:minSdkVersion` attribute in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file has been set to or below the version of the phone. However, the functionality which relies on the later libraries won't work.

The reason I thought the Google IO 2011 app came with a default v7 library is that I created a project from the source in eclipse - I didn't import a project.

(And I'll write it here since I can - The Fragment code written into v11 code for convenience can't be used if you intent to use Fragments pre v11 as `android.app.Fragment` isn't compatible with `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. It just needs to be ignored and hooks retrieved from `getSupportManager()` etc.).

So, I withdraw my question :)